# Air Application integrating to Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to build an Adobe Air application that makes calls to our server running our Wordpress installation.

I would be looking for the user to log into the application and then be able to select from a list of posts.

I have already tried to build functions that integrate to the admin_ajax.php file but obviously because of server restrictions this cannot be achieved.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Adobe Air application wants to read some kind of XML response, Wordpress actually isn't a good fit to do this. Before you know it, you're hard coding less-than and greater-than signs as text, concatenating strings in between.

I have been there and it is a world of pain.

If at all possible I would actually create a separate directory on the web server and create regular PHP files in there, using built-intools to create the XML. You can just connect to the Wordpress database using PHP.